# An error in proving an inequality for $\frac{1}{\zeta}$ in Stein and Shakarchi Complex Analysis Chapter 7 Proposition 1.6?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, inequality, complex-numbers, prime-numbers

On page 187, Stein and Shakarchi says

> $\zeta(\sigma+it) \geq c |\zeta^{-3}(\sigma)||t|^{-\epsilon}\geq c' (\sigma-1)^{3}|t|^{-\epsilon}$ for all $\sigma, |t| \geq 1$.

The implication of this proof is clearly that $\zeta(\sigma)\leq\frac{C}{\sigma-1}$ for all $\sigma\gt 1$. However, isn't this impossible, as $\zeta(\sigma)\to 1$ as $\sigma \to \infty$, whereas $\frac{C}{\sigma-1} \to 0$ as $\sigma \to \infty$? It is clearly true for $\sigma \to 1$, but not for the other limit. This question has been [raised before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404973/estimates-for-1-zetas?rq=1), but the replies there don't really solve the problem I've raised here. They say it takes the smallest value when s=1, so it suffices to show a lower bound there. But because the bound is dependent on the input, doesn't that make this untrue? Is there a way to fix this proof so it works for all $\sigma \geq 1$ without the constant depending on $\sigma$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Where do prime numbers occur in this question ?

Comment: Prime numbers do not occur explicitly in this question, however this is in the chapter on the Prime Number Theorem in the book, and is used in that proof, so I thought someone interested in such topics may be able to answer. I probably cast too wide a net with my tags, sorry.